# What is the best way to get passwords for basic auth in a API and why?

Tags: api, authentication

Creating a API here and I want people to be able to make simple mobile apps that could get the username/password of my users and of they go to interact with my server. So I need to have a Basic Auth(OAuth and other stuff are also going to be supported, mostly for a different use case). Right now I have a example from a Book saying i could just receive the (unencrypted) password as part of the post and looking at successful APIs I see that twitters gets unencrypted passwords on the headers of their HTTP request.

Another options would be to get md5 or SHA1 hashes, but without a secret salt, this seems like an exercise in futility. I asked a couple of people and everyone had a different(strong and heuristic) point of view, so....

**What is the best way to get passwords for basic auth in a API and why?**

Answer (score 1):

Uh, *do not* give out the passwords of your users to other apps. Or via your API. Or ever. They should be stored 1-way anyway (i.e. hashed).

But I'm not so sure if that is what you are saying. You talk about OAuth (which you can use to generate *tokens* that let API's access various components of your system, because the user says that it is possible).

For example, say you wish to allow API-users to query a certain users properties (say, their location), then you create a token for this access via OAuth, and the API-caller passes that. At least, this is my understanding of the model. Obviously, you should review OAuths webside, and find an appropriate implementation for your given language.

Comment: I don't want to give passwords, i want to get credentials so people can for example post new information linked to their accounts. 

OAuth is useless for a mobile app, because i want third party app creators to be able to ask for a username/password and that's it. With OAuth you need user interaction(to allow the creation of the token) or to somehow receive the password anyway.

Comment: @DFectuoso Have you read this: http://hueniverse.com/2007/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-ii-protocol-workflow/ it handles the flow you want, and I don't see that the application being mobile-based should make a difference.